# Installing Sonata Page Bundle Error with Symfony 2.8.*

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am trying to install Page Bundle From Sonata Project. For some reason i cant install it because of the dependancy.

```
   composer require sonata-project/page-bundle
Using version ^2.3 for sonata-project/page-bundle
  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.9 requires sonata-project/seo-bundle ~1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.8 requires sonata-project/seo-bundle ~1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.7 requires sonata-project/seo-bundle ~1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.6 requires sonata-project/seo-bundle ~1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.5 requires sonata-project/seo-bundle ~1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.4 requires symfony/symfony >=2.2,<2.4-dev -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.3 requires symfony/symfony >=2.2,<2.4-dev -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.2 requires symfony/symfony >=2.2,<2.4-dev -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.1 requires symfony/symfony >=2.2,<2.4-dev -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/page-bundle 2.3.0 requires symfony/symfony >=2.2,<2.4-dev -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/page-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/page-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Composer.json file is ---

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",

    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",

    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",

    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "^2.3",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
```

}

I tried few other ways to but didn't try downgrading seo-bundle and Symfony 2.8.*.

Thanks for your help in future.

Comment: Have you tried to lower sonata seo bundle version to 1.1? I'm asking this because from sonata page bundle page on packagist I see that v2.0 of sonata seo bundle uses only 2.4.x-dev version of sonata page bundle. Previous versions of sonata page bundle use v1.1 of sonata seo bundle.

Comment: Thanks man.. it worked... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lowered seo-bundle to v1.1 and it worked like a charm.

I am still haveing some other problems, but atleast installation went through.